# Submission form won't stay on same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp, submit

Here is my form:

```
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" size="25" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fn; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $ln; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $un; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $em; ?>">
      <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Repeat Email" value="<?php echo $em2; ?>"/>
      <input type="password" size="32" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <input type="password" size="32" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password"/><br />
      <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!"/>

      </form>
```

When on my site and pressing submit (in xampp) I get an error stating

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

I am somewhat new to coding with php, css, and javascript but I've been trying to find a solution to this for 2 days and I keep coming up with nothing.

I am just trying to get the form to stay on the same page after submitting or pressing sign in!

If anyone could help, that would be great! Thanks for reading.

Comment: try putting action=""

Comment: action="" leave it blank

Comment: I've tried this multiple times. Still no luck!

Answer (score 3):

Specifying no action will submit the form to the current page:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Alternatively use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying so fast. Unfortunately I've tried that already and I still come up with the same message.

Comment: @user2517092 Just try specifying `method`: `<form method="post">` -- if you have other things for a re-direct.. `header ("Location:");` or any js/meta refresh to another page.. Try removing them

Comment: @user2517092 are you doing any kind of redirect after the submission? Maybe you have a bug in some code or a htaccess redirect.

Comment: @MrCode I don't have any other redirects I do have a feeling that I went wrong somewhere in my code but I have no idea where. I've been removing and adding things to try to fix it but I still fall short.